# How do I pass an object from a filter to an action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, shopping-cart

I am having some problems implementing a shopping cart into my ASP.NET Core application. I am using session storage to do this but every time `OnActionExecuted` executes, the cart object passed to the filter is empty. Anyone have any idea why?

Session filter class:

```
public class WinkelmandSessionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private Winkelmand _mand;

    public WinkelmandSessionFilter()
    {
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        _mand = ReadCartFromSession(context.HttpContext);
        context.ActionArguments["cart"] = _mand;
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        WriteCartToSession(_mand, context.HttpContext);
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
    }

    private Winkelmand ReadCartFromSession(HttpContext context)
    {
        Winkelmand cart = context.Session.GetString("cart") == null ?
            new Winkelmand() : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Winkelmand>(context.Session.GetString("cart"));
        return cart;
    }

    private void WriteCartToSession(Winkelmand cart, HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Session.SetString("cart", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cart));
    }
}
```

The method that uses this filter:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(WinkelmandSessionFilter))]
public IActionResult BonEdit(Winkelmand mand, NieuwViewModel model)
{
    var bon = new Bon();
    bon.NaamGeadreseerde = model.naamGeadreseerde;
    bon.EmailGeadreseerde = model.emailGeadreseerde;
    bon.NaamGever = model.naamGever;
    bon.Bedrag = model.Bedrag;
    bon.Boodschap = model.Boodschap;
    bon.Winkel = model.Winkel;
    bon.BonId = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode();
    mand.bonToevoegen(bon);
    bon.genereerPdf();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(BonVoorbeeld), bon);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the cart to the action using the name `cart`:

```
context.ActionArguments["cart"] = _mand;
```

But when you are accessing it from the action method, the name is `mand`:

```
public IActionResult BonEdit(Winkelmand mand, NieuwViewModel model)
```

In order for it to be passed into the action method, these 2 names **must match**.

```
context.ActionArguments["mand"] = _mand;
```